# HTML5 : input=month : User able to enter >4-digits for the year

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am using the following code:

```
<input type="month" id="monthYear" name="monthYear" value="" required="true" max="2014-08">
```

However a Chrome user (tested with v 36.0) can still manually type in the month and year (instead of using the native date picker tool).

When it comes to entering the year the user can manually type in up to 6 character.  Is there a way to prevent this as the max attribute does not seem to make a difference?

Comment: _Month: HTML5 A control for entering a month and year, with no time zone._ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

Comment: Does good old `maxlength` work here?

Comment: @iStimple can't you prevent it in client side using ajax?

Comment: Can you not simply validate before submitting the form or sending via an AJAX call (whichever you're doing)?  Validate at server-side as well, as suggested by @iStimple but client-side is better for user experience.